# Iterating through ruby array of hashes in HAML

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I have an array of hashes that I am passing to a HAML page.

```
array = [{"name" => "a", "age" => 1}, {"name" => "b", "age" => 2}]
```

I want to iterate and display this information. I have tried doing this

```
#{locals[:array]}.each do |#{:value}|
%h2 #{:value["name"]}
```

But it doesn't work. The value of the whole hash just get displayed. How do I iterate and display these elements?

In pseudocode, I want to do the following:

```
for each element in array:
print element["name"] // I want to display this information in different HTML tags.
print element["age"]
```

UPDATE: This is my HAML file.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %link{:href => "css/batchscreen.css", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
  %body
    .container
      locals[:array].each do |element|
      .story
        %h2 Name: #{element['name']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use the *String Interpolation* `#{}`, which takes whatever is in the curly brackets and makes a String out of it (calling `to_s` I believe). With the "each" you then want to iterate over the String. Same for the `|#{:value}|`.

Bottom line: Use `#{}` only if you want to include something in a String (sequence of characters).

In your case, you want to write the following in your haml template (be aware that you need proper indentation)

```
- locals[:array].each do |element|
  %h2 Name: #{element['name']}, Age: #{element['age']}
```

Besides, consider using symbols for the hash keys, as in

```
array = [{:name => "a", :age => 1}, {:name => "b", :age => 2}]
```

or even (with newer versions of ruby)

```
array = [{name: "a", age: 1}, {name: "b", age: 2}]
```

And then adjust the String interpolation in the heading (`%h2`) accordingly (it becomes something like `#{element[:name]}`.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, I have updated the question with my haml file.

I get an error `undefined local variable or method `element' `. What is the `-` before your code mean? Do I have to put that in the code?

Comment: It executes ruby code in your haml template (http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_)

Answer (score 2):

the following should do it :

```
- array.each do |elem|
  %h2 name : #{elem["name"]}, age: #{elem["age"]}
```

Comment: I got the following error ```undefined local variable or method `elem' for #``` And ```array``` is in the ```locals``` part of HAML so I did ```#{locals[:array]}.each do |elem| ``` instead of ```array.each do |elem|```